# How can I tell if my "dedicated server" is truely dedicated, or Virtual Dedicated?

Tags: virtual-machine, webserver

I became suspicious when I was in my WHM (CPanel) and saw that my hard drive was "/dev/vda1". Is this an indication that my server is actually a VM?

**EDIT**
I had raised my concerns to my Account Manager at my hosting company. He assures me that it is a VM, but on a dedicated machine, so I am the only VM on that box. I'll look more into it but would still appreciate any answers to the original question.

Comment: I've heard of a few service providers who run systems with a single VM in a container so that its easier to migrate users between hardware, should bad things happen.

Comment: You should expect a ~ 10% performance overhead on CPU and disk from being in a VM. If this is important to you, you should have a chat with your account manager, other service providers, and possibly your attorney.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek and bad things _DO_ happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could very well be the sole VM on the machine, as they might only run *nix on the hardware and use VMs to run Windows.

However, there is no way to know without access to the host machine's virtual machine manager.  You could be the only VM, or one of a hundred.

Comment: I was coming to this conclusion myself. It's supposedly a Linux machine running Linux KVM in order to speed up deployment. That leads me to another question. Not sure if I should ask it separately... Does this virtualization layer hinder the server's performance?

Comment: @TecBrat I would ask that as a separate question, but Server Fault might be better>

Comment: Does it affect performance?  Yes.  Hinder?  Thats a relative question.

Comment: @AthomSfere Thanks for the suggestion. There are so many SE sites, I forget sometimes which ones are available. I'll ask it over there.